# AJAX and Codeigniter - Determining what button has been pressed to update

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have this shopping cart wherein I can add or subtract the quantity of a specific item. The problem is I don't know how to determine if the user has pressed the plus button or the minus button.

**HTML code of the plus/minus**

```
<td>
   <div class="input-group" style="width: 100px !important;">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
         <button class="btn btn-danger btn-minus" type="button">-</button>
      </span>
      <input class="form-control table-shopping-qty" type="text" id = "<?php echo $cartrow['id']?>" value="<?php echo $cartrow['qty']?>" style="padding-left:5px;text-align: center;"/>
      <span class="input-group-btn">
         <button class="btn btn-success btn-plus" type="button">+</button>
      </span>
   </div><!-- /input-group -->
</td>
```

**AJAX Function**

```
function updateShoppingCart(){
var productid = $(".table-shopping-qty").attr("id");
dataString = {productid: productid};

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"+"listproductscontroller/editcart_item",
  data: dataString,
  cache: false,
  success: function(){
    swal('Success!', 'Cart updated!', 'success');
  }, error: function(){
    swal('Oops!', 'Something went wrong. Please try again later', 'error');
  }
});
```

}

**Controller**

```
public function editcart_item(){
  $id = $this->input->post('productid');

  if($this->session->userdata('cartsession')){
    $cartsession = $this->session->userdata('cartsession');
    foreach($cartsession as $row){
      if($row['id'] == $id){
        $updated = array('id'=>$row['id'], 'qty'=>$row['qty'] - 1);
      }else{
        $updated = array('id'=>$row['id'], 'qty'=>$row['qty']);
      }
    }
    $this->session->set_userdata('cartsession', $updated);
  }

  if($this->session->userdata('cartsession')!=NULL){
    if($this->cartdata = $this->ProductModel->getProductToCart($this->session->userdata('cartsession'))){
      $this->session->set_userdata('globalcart', $this->cartdata);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So far I have tried to get its ID but then I have the problem of getting its value since it depends from the session and not the added/subtracted qty itself

Answer (score 0):

load `url` helper in controller.using `$this->load->url('url');`.Then

```
function updateShoppingCart(){
var productid = $(".table-shopping-qty").attr("id");
dataString = {productid: productid};

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "<?php echo base_url('listproductscontroller/editcart_item');?>",
  data: dataString,
  cache: false,
  success: function(data){
    alert("success");
  }, error: function(){
    alert("failed");
  }
});
```

Don't forget to set

```
$_config['base_url'] ="your_domain_name";
```